# Cron Job (PHP) Whats the best way to design the code for easy debug and clarity

Tags: php, cron

I have a PHP cron job which is a long file that does 25 different jobs like updating users from memcache to databases, statistical calculations and more.

Its hard to maintain and badly written so I'm going to redesign it.

What is the recommended way to write complex multi steps cron jobs ?

Also is there some way to make the scheduling of different tasks in the cron jobs more streamlined?
For example some of the tasks are better done continuously or called at a higher frequency as possible while others are better not done in parallel to one another. etc...

Comment: My simple and easy advice is to following the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle : don't write one file that does 25 different jobs, write 25 different files (and do not duplicate code, use inclusion for the common part).

Comment: Use different files for each cron jobs... Write functions in global file and include this in each cron job file. Whats the problem? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it is by having the cronjobs inside a table. And have an OS cronjob that runs a php file that checks that table and executes he needed cronjobs.

The advantage of using a database is that you can keep track of the jobs and define the frequency. Cronjobs that didn't not run for any reason, will be retried.

So I would suggest creating different files for each cronjob, and registering them in a database.